Route traffic to endpoint outside of wireguard tunnel via specific wireguard peer
I have a vpn wireguard setup as shown below between PeerA and PeerB. There is also an HTTPS endpoint not part of the WG tunnel - 192.168.2.10:443.
PeerB can netcat the HTTPS endpoint as expected:
root@peerB:~# nc -vz 192.168.2.10 443
Connection to 192.168.2.10 443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
root@peerB:~# 

PeerA times out when trying the same:
root@peerA:# nc -vz 192.168.2.10 443
192.168.2.10: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [192.168.2.10] 443 (?) : Connection timed out
root@peerA:#

I'd like to avoid putting the HTTPS endpoint on wireguard and make use of a routing table and some rules on PeerB to allow PeerA to netcat the HTTPS endpoint. Currently my setup looks as such:
PeerA (realIP: 172.16.1.5 - wgIP: 10.10.10.5)
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private_key for PeerA>
ListenPort = 51820
FwMark = 0

[Peer] #VPN Gateway
PublicKey = <public_key for vpn gateway>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = vpn-endpoint.com:51820

[Peer] #PeerB
PublicKey = <public_key for PeerB>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.15/32, 192.168.2.10/32
Endpoint = 192.168.1.15:51820

PeerB (realIP: 192.168.1.15 - wgIP: 10.10.10.15)
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private_key for PeerB>
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.10.10.15/32
PostUp = ip route add 192.168.2.10/32 dev wg0 table custom_table && ip rule add from 10.10.10.5/32 lookup custom_table

[Peer] #VPN Gateway
PublicKey = <public_key for vpn gateway>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.1/32
Endpoint = vpn-endpoint.com:51820

[Peer] #PeerA
PublicKey = <public_key for PeerA>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.5/32
Endpoint = 172.16.1.5:51820

-----------------
# Routing table for PeerB:
root@peerB:~# ip r show table custom_table
192.168.2.10 dev wg0 scope link
root@peerB:~#


You're going to need to add routes on peer A that tell it "to reach 192.168.2.10, use peer B".

In theory yes, however adding a route to 192.168.2.10 on PeerA that goes via the peerB address on the wireguard interface didn't solve the issue. tcpdump on PeerB says that endpoint is unresolvable when trying to netcat from PeerA, however a netcat from PeerB still works as expected. May just end up putting the endpoint on wg as this whole exercise may not be worth it.
